# Fire up ajax request when some inputs has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following inputs:

```
 <input class="input-text" type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" />
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="apellidoP" id="apellidoP" />
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="apellidoM" id="apellidoM" />
    <input class="input-text" type="text" name="nacimiento" id="nacimiento" />
```

I want to make an ajax request when the "nombres" and "nacimiento" inputs has changed and are not empty, and when "apellidoP" or "apellidoM" also has changed and are not empty.

How can I do that with jQuery? The only solution I have in mind is to trigger "change" event of every input and check if conditions are met, do you have another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in completed changes to field values you may want to look into jQuery's [blur handler](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Answer (score 1):

That's generally the way you will do it, check for the requirements in the change event.

Answer (score 0):

Your talking about javascript events.  Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp

The following would execute `checkEmail()` whenever you changed something.  Just check the text value of the input element in your function before doing whatever you wanted.

```
<input type="text" size="30" id="email" onchange="checkEmail()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nombres').change(function(){
if($(this).val() !== '') {
//function to execute
}
});
```

Same applies for apellidoP and apellidoM.